# Does temperature affect ionic strength?

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, solubility, buffer

Hello I apologize if this is a dumb question but if I have a phosphate buffer made up of Na2HPO4 and NaH2PO4 and I gradually increase the temperature (lets say 10,20,30,40,50) what would happen to the ionic strength. Would it remain the same or change?

Comment: As solution density and acid dissociation constants depend on T - what would you say ? another question is - Can you afford to consider it constant ?

Comment: I was wondering how would it change. Would it increase as the temperature increases? Im rather confused so if my question doesn't make a lot of sense thats why

Comment: also thank you for your response

Comment: Consider that even pure water increasingly dissociates with higher temperature, so the pH of plain water at 25°C is 7.0, but at 50°C is 6.63 (remember pH is a negative logarithmic value, so "less is more" ionized.). See https://www.westlab.com/blog/how-does-temperature-affect-ph